# Android: On resuming Activity, unable to post Runnable on Activity's View

Tags: android, textview, android-activity, resume, ui-thread

I have an `Activity` with a `TextView`, and I set the label and color of the `TextView` each time a background thread invokes a method on the `Activity`. It works properly until I leave the `Activity` and re-enter it. In that case, the `TextView` is not updated because the `Runnable` that is posted for execution on the UI thread is not invoked. Perhaps I need to implement something in `onResume()`, but I don't know what that would be.

Here is how the `TextView` is assigned when the `Activity` is created:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_manage_nameserver);
        statusView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statusNameserverButton);
        ...
}
```

And here's the method called by the background thread, which updates the `TextView`:

```
public void running(boolean running) {
        final int color;
        final String text;
        if (running) {
            color = Color.GREEN;
            text = "Running";
        } else {
            color = Color.RED;
            text = "Stopped";
        }
        statusView.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                statusView.setTextColor(color);
                statusView.setText(text);
            }

        });
}
```

In the debugger I see that when `running()` is invoked after I've re-entered the `Activity`, the `Runnable` passed to `statusView.post()` is never invoked. Inspection of the `statusView` object properties in the debugger shows no difference between the success and failure cases. I don't know what's different after resuming the `Activity` that would cause the `Runnable` to not be invoked. I tried re-assigning the `TextView` object in `onResume()`, with the same code used to assign it in `onCreate()`, but that didn't help.

Comment: First check to see if the Activity after resume is the same one as the original Activity, the original Activity may have been destroyed by Android. Also, check to see if `statusView.post(...)` returns true.

Comment: Thanks Kai, that enabled me to solve the problem. Please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it and make the solution evident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check to see if the Activity after resume is the same one as the original Activity, as the original Activity may have been destroyed by Android. Also, check to see if `statusView.post(...)` returns true.

Comment: The Activity was being created again each time I navigated to it. The class that updates the Activity with status is a singleton, and I only registered the originally-created Activity on it. This Activity, presumably not garbage-collected because the singleton class retained a reference to it, was being notified; and it no longer had a UI context, I assume.

I fixed it by registering the Activity with the singleton on each call to onCreate(). When a new Activity is registered, the singleton disposes the TimerTask that was keeping a reference to the previous Activity instance.

Comment: @MidnightJava Using this method, you will always hold 2 instances of the same Activity at the same time at least for a brief moment, which is not desirable. A quick fix would to be store the reference to Activity as a WeakReference: 
`private WeakReference<Activity> mainRef = new WeakReference<Activity>(mainActivity);` and to do this each time you want to use the reference: `Activity mainActivity = mainRef.get();
   if (mainActivity != null) {...}`